# FragmentActivity Tab screen Blackout

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm using the android sample, [FragmentTabs](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentTabs.html) .

Say, there are 4 tabs(A,B,C,D). I replace the tab fragment(A) with another (E), by using this code

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();

        transaction.replace(R.id.realtabcontent, newFragment);
        transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

        // Commit the transaction
        transaction.commit();
```

In another tab C, when I press back Button the tab (A) screen become black.

Comment: [Android Tabs with Fragments](http://android.codeandmagic.org/2011/07/android-tabs-with-fragments/) and Also See this Developer Site [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) Hope it Helps.

Answer (score 2):

Hi Ashish this issue is happening because fragment cant understand like normal back activity in normal activity when you press back key at that time the recently used activity will automatically open but in fragment it will not happen when you press back button,so we have to maintain back event in fragment here i am sharing the code from which i am handling my fragment activity so may be you can check this

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        showDetail(position);

    }

    void showDetail(int position) {
        this.position=position;
        if(isDualPane){
            getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
            DetailFragment detailFragment = (DetailFragment)
                    getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.detail);

            if (detailFragment == null || detailFragment.getIndex() != position ) {
                detailFragment = new DetailFragment(position);
                FragmentTransaction ft =getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.detail, detailFragment);
                ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                ft.commit();
            }

        }
        else {
            Intent intent =new Intent();
            intent.setClass(getActivity(),DetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("position", position);
            startActivity(intent);


        }
```

see the else part is showing that intent is maintaining my fragments

please check my example(Fragment With Gridview)which i have share here for all fragment users you will find some thing helpful from it

check my answer on this link: [How to Show Different Layouts inside Fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10942959/how-to-show-different-layout-in-fragments/10943192#10943192)

Answer (score 1):

You're most likely adding the first Fragment transaction to the back stack. When adding a transaction to the back stack, that means that when the user hits back, the last transaction will be reversed. So if you added Fragment A and removed Fragment B, then pressing back will remove Fragment A and add Fragment B (and restore some saved state for Fragment B).

For your first transaction, you are just adding a Fragment to the Activity, so reversing that will remove the Fragment and, thus, display nothing. So just don't add the first transaction to the back stack (Assuming you did that...I have no way of knowing because you only pasted a small snippet of your code).

Answer (score 0):

I typically use the android sample, [FragmentTabs](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentTabs.html), for managing tabs, and I haven't experienced this issue.  Without see the full source code, it is hard to tell exactly what it happening.  But, if you are not using the `FragmentTabs`, then you can try to migrate to that, since it's been fully tested ;)

Comment: I'm using that android sample as well. But still getting screen Blackout as I described above.