# How to Show Different Layouts inside Fragments

Tags: android-layout, android-fragments

I am working with two fragments in Android Honeycomb (Tab). In the left is a `ListView` and in the right is a preview of the item selected from the list. When one of the buttons is clicked, I want to show different layouts on the left. How is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this, I made the same thing with use of these links, here is my code which I am sharing with you in the hope that it will be helpful for you... You will first have to create 4 layouts. 2 of which will be for landscape mode, one for portrait mode and another for tablets. You have to create a couple more folders for layouts and their name should be like `layout-xlarge` and `layout-xlarge-port`, this way you can create fragments for both mobile devices and tablets.

**MasterFragment Activity:**

```
public class MasterFragment extends ListFragment {
    Boolean isDualPane;
    int position;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        ArrayList<String> parkNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Park park : Resort.PARKS) {
            parkNames.add(park.getName());
        }

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parkNames));
        View detailFrame = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.detail);
        isDualPane = detailFrame != null && detailFrame.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            position = savedInstanceState.getInt("position", 0);
        }

        if (isDualPane) {
            getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
            showDetail(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt("position", position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        showDetail(position);
    }

    void showDetail(int position) {
        this.position = position;
        if (isDualPane) {
            getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
            DetailFragment detailFragment = (DetailFragment) getFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.detail);

            if (detailFragment == null || detailFragment.getIndex() != position) {
                detailFragment = new DetailFragment(position);
                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.detail, detailFragment);
                ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                ft.commit();
            }
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("position", position);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

**Second Activity - DetailFragment Activity:**

```
public class DetailActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.detail_act);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        int position = bundle.getInt("position");
        System.out.println("RR : position is : " + position);

        Integer[] images = { R.drawable.pic1, R.drawable.pic2, R.drawable.pic3,
                R.drawable.pic4, R.drawable.pic5, R.drawable.pic6,
                R.drawable.pic7, R.drawable.pic8, R.drawable.pic9,
                R.drawable.pic10, R.drawable.pic11, R.drawable.pic12,
                R.drawable.pic13 };

        final ImageView imgview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imgview.setImageResource(images[position]);

        // DetailFragment detailFragment = new DetailFragment(position);
        // FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        // FragmentTransaction ft =fm.beginTransaction();
        // ft.add(android.R.id.content, detailFragment).commit();

    }
}
```

Now you have to create a third activity, `MasterGridActivity` for my images which I am using for showing in fragment in `GridView`.

```
public class MasterGridActivity extends Fragment {

    Boolean isDualPane;
    GridView gridView;
    ListView listView;
    int position;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview, container, false);

        gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridViewImage);
        gridView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(view.getContext()));

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View detailFrame = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.detail);

        isDualPane = detailFrame != null && detailFrame.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos, long arg3) {
                if (!isDualPane) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setClass(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("position", pos);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    DetailFragment detailFragment = (DetailFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.detail);

                    if (detailFragment == null || detailFragment.getIndex() != pos) {

                        detailFragment = new DetailFragment(pos);
                        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                        ft.replace(R.id.detail, detailFragment);
                        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                        ft.commit();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Now here is my image adapter - `MyAdapter` - for my images which extends a `BaseAdapter`.

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;

    public MyAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) { // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 100));
            imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

    static Integer[] mThumbIds = { R.drawable.pic1, R.drawable.pic2,
            R.drawable.pic3, R.drawable.pic4, R.drawable.pic5, R.drawable.pic6,
            R.drawable.pic7, R.drawable.pic8, R.drawable.pic9,
            R.drawable.pic10, R.drawable.pic11, R.drawable.pic12,
            R.drawable.pic13,
    };
}
```

Now I am sharing the XML files for these fragments.

**Main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/master"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="org.fragment.MasterGridActivity" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**gridview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

  <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridViewImage"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**detail_fragment.xml**: This XML is for showing the detail in another fragment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="8dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="8dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**detail_act.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

  <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Make the same XML for landscape mode and for tablets. It's working fine for me. Hope it will helpful for you.

Comment: sorry, but i can't find "DetailFragment" activity in your program.

Comment: hi,please follow the post here in my answer the second activity is the detail fragment activity.you can follow my example like i post u will defiantly get the full result with it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define an [**event callback to the activity**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html#EventCallbacks) activity callback. That is, your left fragment must first notify the container activity that an event occurred (i.e. one of the list items were selected). The container activity will then pass this information to the right fragment, which will then update its UI accordingly.

I could explain this in more detail, but there are several [**tutorials**](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/02/android-30-fragments-api.html) on the internet that teach just that. I suggest you read through some of [**them**](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_fragments/), as the concept will make a lot more sense once you do.